# How to check if result exist on array query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i have a problem that is driving me nuts. Maybe you can help me out. I have something like this:

```
$result_listas = mysqli_query($link, "some mysql query");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_listas, MYSQLI_BOTH))
{
  for($i=$resultado_min['id']; $i<=$resultado_max['id']; $i++)
  { 
    if ($row[id]=$i) 
    {
    echo "The '$i' element exist in the array";
    }
    else
    {
    echo"$i does not exist in the query";
    }
  }
}
```

Basically what i want to do is check if '$i' exist as an ID within the '$result_listas' query. I'm sure is quite simple but i've being programming all day and my brain is melted! thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or try

```
if(in_array($i, $row)){
    //It Exists
}
```

For your example, try:

```
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result_listas, MYSQLI_BOTH);
for($i=$resultado_min['id']; $i<=$resultado_max['id']; $i++) { 
    if (in_array($i, $row2)){
        echo "The '$i' element is in the array"; 
    } else{echo"nada";} 
}
```

Comment: should be in_array(value, array)

Comment: $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result_listas, MYSQLI_BOTH);
    for($i=$resultado_min['id']; $i<=$resultado_max['id']; $i++)
    {
    if (in_array($i, $row2['id']))    {
    echo "The '$i' element is in the array";
    }
    else{echo"nada";}
    }

and i get this error:  in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given

Comment: You were specifing a value, not an array. $row2['id'] is a value, not an array. $row2 is your array.

Comment: I tried that: if(in_array($i, $row2)) and also got the same error. It's driving me nuts!...it's seems easy but i dont know why is not working!

Comment: and the array is ok cos i tried to echo the result and is working

Comment: you can echo an array? Usually I just get: Array() when I echo an array. Try var_dump($row2) and ensure it is actually coming out as an array.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
if ($row[id]=$i)
```

with

```
if ($row['id']==$i) // Note the single quotes and also the == operator
```

Comment: I tried that but im getting the "else" result ("$i does not exist in the query") i dont know why

Comment: That's because this method only checks it one time. You'd have to cycle through the whole array to check for true whereas in_array does all that for you.